# Create a hidden character field?

Tags: 7, users, entities

How can I create a hidden character field in D7 for a text field that hides the user input like the password field does? For example a field called "social security number" should not display the users input in plain text, but instead hide the input. Is there a module that can do this? Or how would that be realized?

Comment: What is the issue to use '#type' => 'password',  field?

Answer (score 3):

You can with `'#type' => 'password'` in  your form.

Ex:

```
$form['social_sec'] = array(
  '#type' => 'password',
  '#title' => t('Social Security'),
  '#description' => t('Please enter your social security number'),
  '#size' => 9,
  '#maxlength' => 9,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

If you want this as a field in a node's form, then you will have to use [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) and alter an already existing field.

Comment: a convention like type=hidden would be too easy, right? Typical Drupal, why make it easy if you can also make it complicared .... ggggrrrrrrr

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I think it's because they are following [regular HTML form type convention for password fields](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_password)